NestJS gRPC is not parsing full response
I am new to gRPC and trying to learn by creating something in NestJs.
but I am stuck on a weird problem where I am trying to send some data by postman but only getting partial data in return.
I am sending:
{
  "db": "db_test",
  "name": "col_test",
}

but I am receiving only the following in my controller:
{
  "name": "col_test"
}

Here is my .proto file
syntax = "proto3";

package collection;

service CollectionService{
    rpc Create (CreateRequest) returns (CreateResponse) {}
}

message CreateRequest {
    string name = 1;
    string db = 2;
}   

message CreateResponse {
    string name = 1;
    string db = 2;
}

this is my controller:
@Controller()
export class CollectionController {
  constructor() {}

  @GrpcMethod('CollectionService', 'Create')
  create(data: CreateCollectionRequest): CreateCollectionResponse {
    console.log(data); 
    return data;
  }
}

Furthermore, I noticed some strange behavior when I change the numbers in my proto file
message CreateRequest {
    string name = 2; // previous 1
    string db = 1; // previous 2
}   

message CreateResponse {
    string name = 1;
    string db = 2;
}

now it is returning
{
  "db": "col_test"
}

but this value should be part of the name key
changing the numbers should not change the values in the key.
What am I missing here?
Attaching postman screenshot:


Unfamiliar with NestJS but your function signature is incorrect. It should be create(data: CreateRequest): CreateResponse. I suspect that the erroneous result is a consequence of this (and JavaScript's weak typing).
